# How to filter filebeat logs on namespace

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, containers, filebeat

I have cluster where i am running filebeat as demon service and following is the configmap for the same. I want to get logs only from the namespace  `abc`  but I am still getting logs from all the name spaces, specially I am getting logs about filebeat from filebeat which is taking 75% of the space. Is anything wrong with configuration ? Or there is another better way to do it ? Or other way to stop getting the logs from filebeat about filebeat ?

````
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
   filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.autodiscover:
      providers:
        - type: kubernetes
          node: ${NODE_NAME}
          hints.enabled: true
          hints.default_config:
            type: container
            paths:
              - /var/log/containers/*${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log
          templates:
            - condition:
                equals:
                  kubernetes.namespace: abc
    output.logstash:
      hosts: ['${LOGSTAH_HOST:elasticsearch}:${LOGSTASH_PORT:5044}']
    logging.level: "info"```
````

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have still `hints.enabled: true` setting.

IMO you only need this:

```
filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: kubernetes
      templates:
        - condition:
            equals:
              kubernetes.namespace: kube-system
          config:
            - type: container
              paths:
                - /var/log/containers/*-${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log
              exclude_lines: ["^\\s+[\\-`('.|_]"]
```

Or the other way would be to work with annotations on you PODs which should be logged or not.

From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-autodiscover-hints.html)

> Filebeat supports autodiscover based on hints from the provider. The hints system looks for hints in Kubernetes Pod annotations or Docker labels that have the prefix co.elastic.logs. As soon as the container starts, Filebeat will check if it contains any hints and launch the proper config for it

E.g. you can also disable default settings entirely, so only Pods annotated like `co.elastic.logs/enabled: true` will be retrieved:

```
filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: kubernetes
      hints.enabled: true
      hints.default_config.enabled: false
```

Comment: Hi @harry i tried it without the flag but still getting logs form the all the namespaces. My application is setup in another namespace